# Zebra printer - Print from another computer

Tags: javascript, connection, ip, zebra-printers

I have my computer connected to a Zebra printer by USB and I am able to print from the browser. However I want to print from a different computer (connected to the same network) using the browser print sdk.
I'm using browser print sdk version 1.2.1.279 and javascript browser print version 2.0.0.75.

I've tried changing the IP variable from localhost to my IP but I get an error of connection refused.

```
var e = {},
    k = {},
    f = "http://127.0.0.1:9100/";
0 <= navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/7.0") && "https:" === location.protocol && (f = "https://localhost:9101/");
e.Device = function(a) {
    var d = this;
    this.name = a.name;
    this.deviceType = a.deviceType;
    this.connection = a.connection;
    this.uid = a.uid;
    this.version = 2;
    this.provider = a.provider;
    this.manufacturer = a.manufacturer;
    this.sendErrorCallback = function(c) {};
    this.sendFinishedCallback = function(c) {};
    this.send = function(c, a, l) {
        var b = g("POST", f + "write");
        b && (h(d, b, a, l), b.send(JSON.stringify({
            device: {
                name: this.name,
                uid: this.uid,
                connection: this.connection,
                deviceType: this.deviceType,
                version: this.version,
                provider: this.provider,
                manufacturer: this.manufacturer
            },
            data: c
        })))
    };
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: If that is the code running on the remote computer, then you will need to use a different IP address than 127.0.0.1 (that is the loopback address - same as localhost - and is only accessible from the same machine).

Comment: Yeah I know. I've tried changing it to my public IP:9100 and it still doesn't work. I've opened the 9100 port on my router as well